# К каким изделиям относятся, перечисленные термины?

Tags: семантика, синтаксис

Швейные и трикотажные изделия (изделия швейные и трикотажные бельевые, изделия чулочно насочные). Как правильно понимать, перечисленные в скобках термины относятся только к <трикотажным изделиям> или же и к <швейным>.

Answer (score 1):

К швейным и трикотажным, так как в скобках есть оба эти слова.